# Definition of determinant w.r.t $n$-linear form

Tags: linear-algebra

In Halmos's book,the definition of the determinant of linear map $A$ on an $n$ dimensional vector space is as follows:

Suppose $A$ is a linear map on $n$ dimensional vector space $V$, $w$ is an alternating $n$-linear form on $V$,then $detA$ is defined as 
$$w(Ax_1,Ax_2,\cdots,Ax_n)=detA\ w(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n).$$
In the definition, it can be seen that $detA$ is independent with the choice of $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$. I don't know how to prove it,can anyone help?

Comment: It follows from linearity of $w$ (you should define $w$ just on basis)

Comment: Note that $w_{A}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=w(Ax_1,Ax_2,\cdots,Ax_n)$ is an alternativing $n$-linear form on $V$. I suspect you have a representation for any such form in terms of determinant. The unknown factor is obtained by applying $w_{A}$ to a standard basis.